# Error previewing multiple images inside div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am uploading multiple images from a single input box and want user to see a thumb preview before uploading image to server.

My problem is the thumb previews are being shown outside DIV, like this:

[image]
How do I make those thumbs appear inside the dark area?

My jsfiddle code is *here*.

[image: my output style i need]

Comment: please add your code or here ot jsfiddle

Comment: fiddle for above question http://jsfiddle.net/sanoj908572/jtvLbwfk/

Comment: you need to either set the position, or ..., post your code, to get more precise answer.

Comment: @AlexFilatov added my code in comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

div#uploa by default have a display property set to block, wich meens any added element will be set below the div, so what you need to do, is to set position of the div to relative, then the position of the images to absolute, then control the left property using javascript.

this is exactly the element you need to target

```
output#list {
   position: absolute;
   top: 10;
   left: 230;
}
```

Comment: is there a way to make those five image display in fixed place ,like 3 images on top row and 2 image in next row

Comment: it's not good answer because this position is absolute, and it's solution not extendable

Comment: @AlexFilatov but the above answer is what i need

Comment: @AlexFilatov can you provide us with a more precise answer, for this situation ?

Comment: @lawrence, to create more rows you need to redesign the layout, and use the float property on the span, and it'l be better, if you keep your output outside of the form.

Comment: @OussamaELGOUMRI how to make `class="fileInpu">` align in middle

Comment: i need to margin `10px from left` and `10px from top`

Comment: @lawrence if your going to use fixed width and height then just calculate it manualy, which is not the best idea, but it'l do in this layout, but if you don't know what the width and height are, then you need to center the elememt using javascript, take a look at line 27 at one of my projects https://github.com/oussamaelgoumri/mohamedhamza/blob/master/dev/js/module/basic-structure/eo-featured.js

Comment: @OussamaELGOUMRI i tried to `margin-left:10px;` but its not margining

Comment: .dis1234 { margin: 0 auto; };

Comment: @lawrence you need to target .dis1234, because your using it as a wrapper, and fileInpu height is 100%, so there is no space to do a margin left.

Comment: @lawrence can you upload a picture of the design you want to achieve ?, i can't understand what your up to.

Comment: @lawrence to margin from top use: .dis1234 { top: 10px; }

Comment: check question i have added another image that what i need margin of `.dis123`

Comment: Oh thanks i have been using `margin-top:10px;` to margin from top